# QFields not syncing some layers

Tags: import, qfield, qfieldsync, tablet

I'm running a team project at the moment, several team members out in the field collecting data with the same QField package. When we get back to the office every day we are wanting to sync each tablet's data to a master project file and repackage that for the next field day.

Everything has worked perfectly, except that only two of the 5 layers we are editing in the field has successfully updated data when using QFieldSync by cable in the office. All layers are exactly the same in terms of makeup, all offline editing, all just polygon/point files. I'm at my wits end working out what the issue is.

QGIS version is 3.30.2
QField version is 2.8.4